# How to get the height of a listbox scrollbar "thumb"?

Tags: c++, winapi

What is this thing inside of the red rectangle called?

[image]

Working in creating a custom Listbox/Scrollbars, I'm trying to find a way to get the height of this thing.

Comment: Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

[Parts of a Scroll Bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-scroll-bars#parts-of-a-scroll-bar) explains:

> A scroll bar consists of a shaded shaft with an arrow button at each end and a *scroll box* (sometimes called a thumb) between the arrow buttons.

So the part you're asking about is called a *scroll box* or *thumb*. The latter is more common when you ask developers. That's the name it has in all symbolic constants in the Windows SDK.

You can get the height of a vertical scroll thumb by requesting a [`SCROLLBARINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-scrollbarinfo) through the [`GetScrollBarInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollbarinfo) function. The height (or width) is `xyThumbBottom - xyThumbTop`.

If the `idObject` parameter seems confusing, make sure you understand that [there are two types of scrollbars](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040510-00/?p=39413).